# Flutter Container with Text as child changes size depending on value of text

Tags: android, ios, flutter, mobile, widget

I have a Container widget with a Text widget as child that is used to set the title for my appbar. The problem is that the container takes different sizes if the value for the text widget is given directly as a string or if it is dynamically set from an object.

**Here are some examples:**

Scenario 1:

```
title: Container(
  color: Colors.green,
  child: Text(
    'BUS 82',
    style: TextStyle(
    color: Colors.white,
    fontSize: SizeConfig.safeHeight * 0.03),
  ,
),
```

[output for scenario 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k6dP0.jpg)

Scenario 2:

```
   title: Container(
 color: Colors.green,
 child: Text(
  recipe.title,
  style: TextStyle(
  color: Colors.white,
  fontSize: SizeConfig.safeHeight * 0.03),
 ),
```

),

where recipe is an object that contains the title as a String.

[Output scenario 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X3tGq.jpg)

Can someone help me better understand why the size of the container changes depending if the value for text is hardcoded or received from an object. The recipe object is received in the constructor of the widget.

Answer (score -1):

In your case if you want a container that doesn't change size, you can use:

1. SizedBox -- specify the width. Use this widget if you know the max width of the string
2. Expanded -- the container will expand to the maximum width

Comment: This is not what I asked.. As you can see from the images, the value for the text is the same in both cases, the only difference is if it is given directly as a string literal or from on object. Depending on that the height of the container changes even though the value is literally the same.